# Charging a custom amount with Stripe and Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm going to try and be thorough as possible. So what I'm trying to do is charge a user a percentage of the overall total that is calculated. How do we get the total? Well, the total cost is depended upon the progression of questions the user answers.

If the user needs a specific service then the cost might increase a bit, say to $100, but we're wanting to charge just 10% of that total that constantly changes like stated before. Currently, the amount is hardcoded, but since the amount changes depending on their services select, I can't have it hard coded.

I'm new to Stripe and Node but is there an easy way such as 'document.getElementById'? of something similar? The charge and everything work correctly but I believe I'm getting confused on the routing.

**My HTML form (with the area where the total will be displayed):**

```
<div class="" style="margin-top: 60px;">
   <h2 class="quote-info">Estimated total&#58; $<span id="new_text"></span> USD</h2>
   <h2 class="quote-info">Reservation deposit&#58; $<span id="new_text2"></span> USD</h2>
 </div>


 <!-- Payment form -->
    <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
       <div class="form-row">
       <label for="card-element">
          Credit or debit card
       </label>
       <div id="card-element">
          <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
       </div>

       <!-- Used to display form errors -->
       <div id="card-errors"></div>
       </div>
       <input type="hidden" name="totalAmount" value="1000">
       <button>Submit Payment</button>
     </form>
```

**My script tag that's found at the bottom of my HTML file that contains the form above:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Create a Stripe client
  var stripe = Stripe('my_key_should_go_here');

  // Create an instance of Elements
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      lineHeight: '24px',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');

    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);

    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    var formData = JSON.stringify({
      mytoken: token.id
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/charge",
      data: formData,
      success: function(){alert("done")},
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json"
    });

    // alert("Created a token with value: "+token.id)
    form.submit();
  }
  </script>
```

**And lastly, my app.js file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe')('deleted_key');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Index route
app.get('/charge', (req, res) => {
  res.send();
});

// charge route
app.post('/charge', (req, res) => {
  // const amount = 2500;
  const amount = req.body.totalAmount;

  stripe.customers.create({
    email: "random@gmail.com",
    source: req.body.mytoken
  })
  .then(customer =>  {
    stripe.charges.create({
    amount,
    description:'specified service description here',
    currency:'usd',
    customer:customer.id
  })})
  .then(charge => res.send('success'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

My primary question is this, how would I go about obtaining the amount given in the 'new_text' area in my HTML file to use and charge the user in node?

Answer (score 0):

To use the `getElementById` is to add an ID to your amount field first:

```
<input type="hidden" name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" value="1000">
```

Then you can use the ID to get the value of the field:

```
const amount = document.getElementById("totalAmount").value;
```

Although, I can see that your input type is hidden - is that intentional?